# objective-c if NSURL fails display UIAlertView

Tags: uialertview

I have this NSURL like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jamessuske.com/isthedomeopen/isthedomeopenGetData.php"];
```

and it works fine when I am connected to the internet. But if I am not (or if the user has no signal) I would want an `UIAlertView` to appear. I tried the following code below (with and without the if statement) but my app crashes.

```
if(!url){
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test Message"
                                                            message:@"This is a test"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
}
```

What Am I doing wrong?

What I mean by crashing, I mean my app opens and does not get the data from the URL. I do not see any errors, I just get brought to a page with this highlighter:

```
Thread 6
com.app.root.default-priority 
     - 0 ucol_getVersion
```

Next to it is a window with this hightlighted

```
0x17bbd32: movl 204(%ecx), %edx Thread 6: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 address=0xcc)
```

Comment: in which line do you get crash? what kind of code of the crash?

Comment: You need to show us some more code. `NSURL` is a class for representing URLs. It does not attempt any sort of network connection unless you specifically ask for that using a dedicated API. Thus, it will not return `nil` should the user happen to be offline. Clearly your code then goes on to do something with the URL in question; please give us details of that code

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing only checks if the object `url` is a `NULL` pointer or not. If you want to check if a user has internet connection, I would recommend trying the `Reachability` classes, which can be found easily online. [This](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) one is very useful for me.

Comment: Please don't do this. You almost certainly want to attempt some sort of connection before *then* displaying the error from that to the user

Answer (score 0):

it is recommended to check the Internet availability if you are developing the app with internet connection requirement by the Apple and they are also providing the .h and .m files namely Reachability.h and Reachability.m so please download that files and import to your projects and there is a parameter named "internetConnectionStatus" and by that values use the below alert

```
if (internetConnectionStatus == NotReachable)
{
    UIAlertView *responseAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error"
                                                            message:@"This application requires network connectivity."
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
    [responseAlert show];


}
else
{ //do other stuff here
}
```

you can find the reachability files [Here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) and you can use any Reachability files from github
ThnQ